# No write permission when use Gem install in Amazon Linux 2 EC2

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

My Ruby application is running in Amazon Linux 2 Elastic Beanstalk.
When I deploy the application to the environment, it tell the bunlder is not installed.
I get the below erros when install the bundler, `sudo gem` doesn't work either

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-220 ~]$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0 directory.
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-220 ~]$ sudo gem install bundler
sudo: gem: command not found
```

Can you tell how to get the write permission?

Comment: Your are doing this manually? Try doing this through ebextentions./

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of possibilities yo can try :

```
i: change permission of the directory 
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-220 ~]$ chmod 777 -R /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-220 ~]$ gem install bundler
```

which would give you all rights ( do sudo chmod if it dosent allow you) to the directory

```
ii. get the path of gem and create a sym link to it in /bin 
then sudo gem command would work for you. 

to know the gem binary path just do 

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-220 ~]$ type gem

this would return you current gem binary path

create a sym link  
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-220 ~]$ ln -s gempath /bin/gem 
( gempath here is the output of "type gem" command)

and then "sudo gem install blunder" should work
```